# Windows Store App - XAML - C# - Access ThemeResource in code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a Styles.xaml file where I have declared various colours and styles.

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColour" Color="#FFFF411E"/>
```

I want to access this in code, as I have control and I want to bind the background colour to a Property in an object. This easily done, however, the object is created from the response to a server call and the property could be one of many colours. I could define the colour in code, but as I use the same colour for other controls defined in `XAML` I dont really want to define the same colour twice in the application. So I want a way to be able to access the `SolidColorBrush` brush in code to be able to use it.

Any idea's how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this..

```
 Application.Current.Resources[ "MyColour" ] as SolidColorBrush
```

Comment: It return wrong color if you change RequestedTheme from code.

Answer (score 0):

first you should have a ResourceDictionary  in your xaml or in file.cs.

xaml : `<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>`

code : `Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary
                    {
                        Source = new Uri(@"/" + this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name + ";component/" + @"Styles.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
                    });`

then you can access to it like this

```
SolidColorBrush mycolor = Resources["MyColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
```